# Connect Squirrel SQL to Hive

Tags: hive, squirrel-sql

I followed these steps to connect Squirrel to Hive.

[https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveJDBCInterface#HiveJDBCInterface-IntegrationwithSQuirrelSQLClient](http://Error%20registering%20driver:%20Hive.%20java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:%20org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveDriver%20:%20Unsupported%20major.minor%20version%2051.0)

In the fourth one, I get this error:

> Error registering driver: Hive.
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

How should I do to resolve it ?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to be java version mismatch. Which version are you using?

Comment: @NishuTayal, I am using 6.0.450.6

Comment: please check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the Java version mismatch. You have higher JDK at compile time while lower JDK at runtime.

Here are the General layout for [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout).

```
Java SE 12 = 56 (0x38 hex),
Java SE 11 = 55 (0x37 hex),
Java SE 10 = 54 (0x36 hex),[3]
Java SE 9 = 53 (0x35 hex),[4]
Java SE 8 = 52 (0x34 hex),
Java SE 7 = 51 (0x33 hex),
Java SE 6.0 = 50 (0x32 hex),
```

It is expecting JDK7. So you need to update the JDK version from JDK 6 to 7.